# Can I evaluated a cell in a notebook in a background process?

Tags: front-end, remote-access

I currently run my *Mathematica* on a linux computer through Putty and Xming. Xming provides a graphical display for *Mathematica* windows running on a remote linux computer.

But recently, the network has become quite unstable. A disadvantage of using Xming  is the graphical display will disappear immediately as soon as the network goes down. When the graphical display disappears, all the evaluation that is running stops and is lost.

**So I wonder if there is a way to control to make notebook cell evaluations run in the background when I use the graphical display to run *Mathematica* remotely.** I expect that code running in the background will not be affected by the shutdown of the graphical display.